# Are "Windows Authentication" and Pass-Through Authentication" the same thing?

Tags: asp.net, iis

Windows authentication allows an app to authenticate using the credentials the user logged in to Windows with.  Are Windows Authentication and Pass-Through Authentication the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they are not the same thing.

Windows Authentication is mostly used in an intranet environment where the net administrators know the users accessing their web applications have user accounts within the windows domain. So, if you're working in a corporate Windows environment where people are accessing the web application via company intranet than it becomes more viable.
More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/

Pass-Through Authentication on IIS will try to authenticate the user with their actual identity but then "pass-through" to the application pool identity if that fails. So in that sense, users accessing that web application won't need an windows account.

I think this question might be better off on the https://serverfault.com.